# Passing a subprocedure parameter into set object statement

Tags: vbscript, ms-office

I have a subprocedure that should process word and excel files. In order to make it more generic, I wanted to pass some elements as parameters, instead of writing the same stuff with minor differences several times.

The procedure accepts the extensions of the files, which works just fine. However, I also need to use either appWord.Documents.Open or appExcel.Workbooks.Open to open a file. How can I store it and call it as a parameter of the procedure?

```
ResaveFiles "appExcel.Workbooks", "docx", 12, 0
ResaveFiles "appExcel.Workbooks", "doc", 0, 12
ResaveFiles "appWord.Documents", "xlsx", 56, 51
ResaveFiles "appWord.Documents", "xls", 51, 56


Sub ResaveFiles(appType, srcExtName, srcExtNum, tmpExtNum)
    If lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFileOrig)) = srcExtName then
        <<StartWord>>
                Set objOpenFile = (appType.Open(objFileOrig.path))
                ...
```

So, what I am ultimately aiming at is to have one procedure instead of four, because the only difference between them is the file formats and the application that is being invoked.

I have no problems with the file formats, however, I cannot pass the parameter "appWord.Documents" into Set objOpenFile = (appType.Open(objFileOrig.path)) statement. The version presented above doesn't seem to work because the the parameter is presented as a string.
Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: I dont think you have supplied us with enough info here.  I dont see fso declared in the subroutine, I dont see objFileOrig delcared int he subroutine.   You can use set someVar =  CreateObject(appType) to get an application object for the required app type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already created the objects `appExcel` and `appWord` earlier, then remove the "" marks around them. For example, below opens the blank file for each Word and Excel:

```
Dim oExcel, oWord

set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

TestOpen oExcel.Workbooks, "C:\Test\blank.xlsx"
TestOpen oWord.Documents, "C:\Test\blank.docx"

Sub TestOpen(oApp, sFile)
    Dim oFile
    oApp.Parent.Visible = True
    Set oFile = oApp.Open(sFile)
    Wscript.Echo "File opened: " & oFile.Name
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub

Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oWord = Nothing
```

Example output:

[image: cmd output]